# TableField and ARIA roles (role="presentation")

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the [TableField](https://drupal.org/project/tablefield) module to include a table in one of my content types. How would I go about adding the following ARIA role for accessibility (for screen readers) in all the tables?

```
<table role="presentation">
```